# How can I automatically enter cmd without activiate sconfig as default in Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2016?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, login, microsoft

When Login to Microsoft Hyper-V Server it will firstly execute `sconfig.cmd` .
[image]
However it is a little bit unnecessary for me. I can just type `sconfig` to start it whenever I want.

How can I set cmd as default when I log in the system?

I have tried to modified the registry table. However, Windows' registry table is a little bit messy and I am afraid to cause some terrible disaster when I modify it. Hence I am seeking for a more secure way.

Answer (score 0):

## Procedure:

1. Type `regedit` in cmd.
2. Choose `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`.
3. Delete item `sconfig`.
4. Finally reboot.

NOTE: Every Startup program can be disable by these procedure.